# MYSQL query running at phpmyadmin but not through mysql_query in ActiveCollab

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am working on a module for ActiveCollab. Everything worked fine until today when i try to run a update command on one of the tables. Here is the command:

```
UPDATE `acx_credit_card_vault_recurring` SET `status`='1' WHERE `id`='2'
```

For my unpleasant surprise it did not work. I tried the same command by copy pasting it into phpmyadmin SQL textbox and ran it without any problem.

I deleted the table altogether and created it through script, to make sure there's no permissions related issues (?):

```
$result = DB::execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acx_credit_card_vault_recurring` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`invoice_object_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ccv_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=0");

pr($result);

//Then i inserted a few records, again through module script and tried the update once again.

$result2 = DB::execute("INSERT INTO `acx_credit_card_vault_recurring` (`invoice_object_id`, `ccv_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(4, 2, 0)");

pr($result2);

$result3 = DB::execute("UPDATE `acx_credit_card_vault_recurring` SET `status`='1' WHERE `id`='2'");
pr($result3);
```

All of the above pr(print_r) function printed 1(true) and table was created, populated and updated successfully, in a single go. Now i commented out the CREATE and INSERT code blocks and ran the UPDATE statement alone and to my unpleasant surprise again it would not work again!

In addition to that if i do run first and last statements (CREATE & UPDATE) together the UPDATE works fine. But it does not work if run alone. Also, every time i run it it returns true(1) which means query ran 'without errors' but no records are updated.

This issue seems to be happening only with this table and SQL update statements work fine on other tables of same database.

I can see plenty of users raising same problem in number of questions here but i could not find a satisfactory answer. Most of the answers advised to check the syntax, single quotes, carrots etc., which in my case not an issue i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. It is

```
DB::beginWork('Deleting recurring profile from Credit Card Vault @ ' . __CLASS__);
```

which is called just before running DB::execute command. As this operation is terminated (with an exit()) before the system could mark transaction 'completed'. It resulted into making the system to 'rollback' the recent DB changes it's own methods/functions might have done to the system. It is still a mystery that why UPDATE worked on some tables and not on some though. Thanks for looking at it anyways!

Comment: I was just going to ask if you had found that - great that you came back to post an answer. That eluded me for _days_ at my last gig.

Answer (score 0):

The custom query inside activecollab modules should be written in following format.

```
try {
  DB::beginWork();
  // yourstuff
  DB::commit();
catch (Error $e) {
  DB::rollback();
}
```

If anything goes wrong in yourstuff, the rollback will run.

Also all uncommitted transactions are automatically rolled back on script shutdown so you need to make sure that you are committing transactions that you opened.

Hope this helps.